# How to make the brightness keys work on an HP Folio 13?

Tags: laptop, brightness, 13.04, function-keys

In my HP Folio 13 laptop with Ubuntu 13.04 the brightness control works with the slider in the system **Brightness & Lock** settings, but the brightness function keys don't. Also, the brightness level is set to maximum on every boot.

Is there a way to make them work and make the system keep the brightness level set in the previous session?

Some information about my laptop concering this issue:

```
ls /sys/class/backlight
intel_backlight

ls /sys/class/backlight/*/brightness
/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness

lspci | grep -i vga
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)

uname -a
Linux folio13 3.8.0-19-generic #29-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 17 18:16:28 UTC 2013 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guys it worked for me with this setting in `/etc/default/grub` :

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi_osi="
```

Yep, this is empty value for acpi_osi...

Don't forget to do `sudo update-grub` and restart after you edit the `/etc/default/grub` file.

Comment: Well in my case on pressing Fn + <Brightness Keys> I could see the brightness indicator on the top but brightness wasn't changing at all. I tried what you suggested and after restarting it wasn't even showing the indicator. I removed that line from grub and updated again, restarted and bam! It worked! :) So I guess just running update-grub may solve issue for some. Thanks for that though, I could find a way because of this. :)

Comment: For me, it reads `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`. I tried instead changing `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_backlight=vendor"` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_backlight=vendor acpi_osi="`, but that didn't boot correctly. Instead, `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_backlight=vendor acpi_osi=''"` works and also re-enables the wireless switch on the F12 key. That approach seems better than taking the side effects of removing `quiet splash` from the GRUB command line.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to add a fix that worked for me, because I couldn't find this solution anywhere.

If you have an Intel video card (HD 4000, for example) you can fix it by adding `acpi_backlight=intel_backlight` to your grub options (in the same way as above).

**BEFORE YOU DO THIS:**
Test that you actually have an Intel video card with the following command:

```
echo 200 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

If your brightness changes, then this solution should work for you.

**Please note** that I haven't tested this solution for laptops with multiple video cards (like NVidia Optimus or the like).

Answer (score 1):

To make the brightness function keys work on my laptop I have tried the following configurations (one by one) in `/etc/default/grub`, but none of them worked:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pcie_aspm=force acpi_backlight=vendor"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=linux acpi_backlight=vendor"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

Same thing for the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX variable.

I read about a solution which suggested editing /etc/X11/xorg.conf, but there was no such file in my system.

So far the best workaround I have found is to use **xbacklight** to bind the keys to appropriate commands. This will enable you to easily increase/decrease the brightness, but it won't show the brightness indicator while you do that.

**1)** Install xbacklight by running:

```
sudo apt-get install xbacklight -y
```

**2)** Go into System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Custom Shortcuts

**3)** Add the following bindings:

```
Brightness Down = xbacklight -10
Brightness Up = xbacklight +10
```

**4)** Click on "Disabled" and press your preferred combinations (for me CTRL+F2 and CTRL+F3 works fine)

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug that has been recently been addressed: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/upower/+bug/994745

It is associated with the upstream kernel bug of problems with unplugging not being recognised: 
https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=54621

Hopefully this can be backported to the Raring kernel in the near future.

Comment: I don't have the power indicator problem which occurs in the bugs you mentioned. It appears though that the patch provided in comment #28 of bugzilla fixes also the two special keys for brightness +/- as well as the wireless adapter toggle. I wonder whether there is an easy way to apply that without having to wait for it to be backported.